# Intuition for universal quotient maps

Tags: gn.general-topology, intuition, filters

The universal quotient maps are precisely the descent morphisms in the category of topological spaces. In some papers of Janelidze, Tholen, Sobral, and Reiterman (see for instance [Reiterman-Tholen](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864194900337)), the two characterizations of universal quotient maps below are mentioned.

**Proposition.** For a continuous map $p$, TFAE.

- $p$ is a universal quotient map (i.e., a regular epi that is stable under pullback).
- Fibers of adherence points of filters $\mathscr F$ contain adherence points of $p^\ast \mathscr F$ ($x$ is an *adherence point* of $\mathscr{F}$ if every neighborhood of $x$ has nonempty intersection with every element of $\mathscr{F}$).
- For every open cover $ \left\{ U_i \right\}_{i\in I}$ of a fiber $p^\ast \left\{ b \right\}$, there's a finite $I_0\subset I$ satisfying $b\in\operatorname{int} \left( p_\ast \bigcup_{i\in I_0}U_i\right)$.

I can't seem to find a geometrical way to think of either of these conditions, so I would like some help in finding intuition..

Comment: Some more references should be given; I added one.

Comment: Indeed, complete categorical definitions are often easy to understand but--for non-categorists--a big nuance to search for them. I feel that the materials on MO should be meant  also for non-specialists, especially that they have a good chance to contribute answers now and then. It's more generally, a question of communication and mathematical customs and culture.

Comment: In general, preferably one person provides a service, and many enjoy it; or everybody is supposed to provide a similar service each for themselves, and not many people do it. Instead of general mathematical discussions we have often but minor cliques.